# Did Anglachel intentionaly prick Túrin's foot?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, children-of-hurin

In the story of the children of Húrin, Beleg is granted a gift by King Thingol, and he asks for the sword Anglachel. Melian warns him of the evil of the sword, and says that it will not love the hand that it serves, and won't abide with him long. He chosoes it even so.

> But as Thingol turned the hilt of Anglachel towards Beleg, Melian looked at the blade;  and she said: 'There is malice in this sword. The heart of the smith still dwells in it, and that heart was dark. It will not love the hand that it serves; neither will it abide with you long.'
>
> 'Nonetheless I will wield it while I may,' said Beleg; and thanking the king he took the sword and departed. Far across Beleriand he sought in vain for tidings of Túrin, through many perils; and that winter passed away, and the spring after.

Then, later, it seems her prophecy was fulfilled:

> Beleg drew his sword Anglachel, and with it he cut the fetters that bound Túrin; but fate was that day more strong, for the blade of the Dark Elf slipped in his hand, and pricked Túrin's foot.

The consequences of this mistake were dire, and led to Beleg's death. Seemingly, Melian was correct; the sword did not love him, and intentionally got him killed.

...But then something weird happens. The sword seems to mourn for Beleg.

> And Gwindor gave the sword Anglachel into his hands, and Túrin knew that it was heavy and strong and had great power; but its blade was black and dull and its edges blunt. Then Gwindor said: 'This is a strange blade, and
> unlike any that I have seen in Middle-earth. It mourns for Beleg even as you do.

Of course, this is just Gwindor's interpretation, and maybe nothing else. Except that at the end of the book the sword actually speaks, and blames Túrin for killing Beleg.

> And from the blade rang a cold voice in answer: 'Yes, I will drink your blood, that I may forget the blood of Beleg my master, and the blood of Brandir slain unjustly. I will slay you swiftly.'

So it is safe to say that the sword did care for Beleg, and was sorry to have killed him. So was Melian wrong? Was it by coincidence that her prophecy seemed to have been fulfilled when Beleg accidentally pricked Túrin's foot?

Comment: It is quite possible to have a prickly, harsh, perhaps even vicious personality, and yet at the same time have a heart moved with warm feelings and care.

Comment: The internal conceit is that *The Silmarillion* consists of stories in the Eldarin tradition translated by Bilbo. As such, the more fanciful episodes can be explained away as inventions of Bilbo, if not earlier Eldarin storytellers. There's no need to assume Anglachel possessed any sort of sentience or awareness as depicted in the story.

Comment: That is, did Beleg die while rescuing Túrin? Sure. Was it due to a cursed blade, or just an unfortunate accident in the dark with an unwieldy weapon? Probably the latter.

Answer (score 6):

Anglachel/Gurthang is essentially a cursed sword, forged by the 'dark elf' Eöl and only reluctantly surrendered to Thingol.

> "There is malice in this sword. The dark heart of the smith still dwells in it. It will not love the hand it serves, neither will it abide with you long."
> —Melian on Anglachel

The wounding of Túrin and the subsequent slaying of Beleg are a manifestation of this curse. It's almost certainly inspired inspired by [Tyrfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrfing) in Norse mythology.

> The dwarfs made the sword, and it shone and gleamed like fire. However, in revenge they cursed it so that it would kill a man every time it was drawn and that it would be the cause of three great evils. They finally cursed it so that it would also kill Svafrlami himself.

(As an aside, the two dwarves that forged Tryfing were named Dvalinn and Durinn, names Tolkien adapted as Dwalin and Durin in his mythology.)

Eöl is one of the most prideful and malevolent characters in canon, responsible for the kidnapping of Aredhel, the sister of Turgon, and her eventual death. His final act before his execution is to curse his son Maeglin, the betrayer of Gondolin.

The accidental wounding of Túrin and Beleg's death is the curse manifesting itself. This probably shouldn't be construed as intentional; while the sword is sentient to some degree, it's not really in control of its fate. When Turin kills himself on the sword it is broken and the curse ended.

Gurthang speaking to Turin is a direct callback to the Norse legend of [Kullervo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullervo), the inspiration for the Tale of Turambar.

> When he returns home, he finds the dead bodies of his own family littered about the estate. His mother's ghost speaks to him from her grave and advises him to take his dog and go to the wild woods for shelter. He does so, but instead of finding shelter, he only discovers the place by the river where he'd seduced his sister, the earth still mourning out loud of his ruining of her: no plants grow in the spot where he'd slept with her, either.

> Kullervo then asks of Ukko's sword if it will have his life. The sword eagerly accepts, noting that as a weapon it doesn't care whose blood it drinks—it's drunk both innocent and guilty blood before. Kullervo commits suicide by throwing himself on his sword. On hearing the news, Väinämöinen comments that children should never be given away or ill-treated in their upbringing, lest like Kullervo they fail to attain understanding and a man's discretion.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Knight of Few Words answer and have upvoted it, but I'll add a speculation:

As the story says, the sword is cursed and the dark heart of its maker dwells in it, but there is a distinction between the sword (which appears to have some being and will of its own) and the curse or dark heart of the maker which is in it. The sword *is* cursed to do things it would not otherwise choose to do.  It does them, but afterwards regrets the action.

This is a perfect parallel with so many heroes who come to have cursed weapons and do great evil with them, regretting it afterwards.

It's unclear that JRRT intended the sword to have that much agency, though.